# "Error starting Spring Boot application", only when trying 'docker-compose up'. Issue with spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-compose, spring-security-oauth2

I'm encountering an error while trying to execute `docker-compose up` with my Spring Boot application. The error message indicates that an attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. However, the method `deviceAuthorizationEndpoint` is present. I was able to locate it through browsing in External Libraries in IntelliJ and actually see its contents.

Weird thing is that the application starts without any issues when I run it.

Trying to follow [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-postgresql-docker) tutorial

This is my full process:

`./mvnw clean package -DskipTests`

Created Dockerfile in src/main/docker and copying my jar in the same folder:

`FROM openjdk:17-oracle ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]`

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: 'docker-spring-boot-postgres:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/compose-postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=compose-postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=compose-postgres
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=compose-postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=compose-postgres
```

And when I do `docker-compose up` I get the error:

```
app  | 
app  | ***************************
app  | APPLICATION FAILED TO START
app  | ***************************
app  | 
app  | Description:
app  | 
app  | An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
app  | 
app  |     org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.server.servlet.OAuth2AuthorizationServerPropertiesMapper.asAuthorizationServerSettings(OAuth2Authorizat
ionServerPropertiesMapper.java:56)
app  | 
app  | The following method did not exist:
app  | 
app  |     'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings$Builder org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorizatio
n.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings$Builder.deviceAuthorizationEndpoint(java.lang.String)'
app  | 
app  | The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.server.servlet.OAuth2AuthorizationServerPropertiesMapper, was loaded from the f
ollowing location:
app  | 
app  |     jar:file:/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/server/servlet/OAuth2Autho
rizationServerPropertiesMapper.class
app  | 
app  | The called method's class, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings$Builder, is available from the following 
app  |
app  |
app  | Action:
app  |
app  | Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.server.ser
vlet.OAuth2AuthorizationServerPropertiesMapper and org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings$Builder
app  |
app exited with code 1
```

I tried mvn clean install and invalidating caches in IntelliJ, tried double-checking that I have the latest versions of all dependencies, nothing helped, the issue persists. I'm using Spring Boot version 3.1.0, spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server version 1.1.0.

Here's my full pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.online-shop</groupId>
    <artifactId>OnlineShop</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <name>OnlineShop</name>
    <description>Online shop project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.amqp/spring-rabbit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What could be the issue?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are mixing different spring boot versions for example `spring-security-oauth2` (version: `2.5.2.RELEASE` )... you are inheriting from spring boot 3.1.0... manually adding versions for components while most of them are handled by the spring-boot parent...

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I completely replaced my pom.xml with the one gerenated by https://start.spring.io/, plus added three io.jsonwebtoken dependencies because it's not available there. And I'm still getting the same error. 

There's no explicit version tags currently in my pom.xml except for the spring-boot-starter-parent and io.jsonwebtoken dependencies.

What do you think could be the issue? I'm thinking of just creating a fresh project from scratch...

For some reason spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.1.jar is still being used according to the error

Comment: Needless to say, I did mvn clean install after replacing the pom.xml and did the whole process again mentioned in my post

Comment: Just tried creating a fresh project using start.spring.io WITHOUT any resource server or authorization server. I still get the same error. Well I got no explanations...

Comment: After everything failed, tried searching for 'spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.1.jar' on my local disk and found it in the local Maven directory.

So I deleted the directory C:\Users\user\.m2\repository

But it didn't help.

Then I tried these but still get the same error:

Invalidated Caches in IntelliJ (File > Invalidate Caches)

Deleted target file

Deleted everything in IntelliJ's caches folder: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.3\caches
Restarted my computer

Answer (score 0):

After fixing my pom.xml I tried many things including trying earlier Spring Boot versions, different JDKs, deleting local maven repository and caches, nothing helped.

In the end I tried it on a different machine and it worked. So yeah, that's the solution. Apparently the old version of that dependency is still somewhere on my local disk.